# Is it possible to create a C FILE object to read/write in memory

Tags: c++, file, memory

I am using an API that takes a `FILE *` and am using that to create a data buffer in memory:

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> f(tmpfile(), fclose);
write_to_file(f.get());
rewind(f.get());
auto data = make_file_buffer(f.get());
return data;
```

This works, but is slower than writing to a memory buffer.

Is it possible to get this to write to a memory file and avoid reading/writing to disk (like stdin/stdout/stderr read/write to the console)?

NOTE: I am using Linux, so have access to Linux and POSIX APIs.

Comment: You can open a file in /dev/shm on Linux, which exists purely in memory.

Comment: This is not C, you are using C++ constructs.

Comment: @wildplasser The API I am using -- `FILE *`, `tmpfile`, `fclose`, `rewind` (along with the `fputc`, `fwrite`, etc. calls in `write_to_file`) -- are C APIs defined in `stdio.h`. This is why I tagged it as `C` as I was after a C function that returned a `FILE *` to a memory buffer. I used C++ constructs to show how I was using the C API.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, see [fmemopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream).

Comment: I never actually knew about that. +1 :).

Comment: @slugonamission lol, me neither. And it sounds like a useful thing. +1.

Comment: There is also `open_memstream` from that link that allocates the buffer for you and gives you its location and size. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How would one do this on Windows?

Comment: @AryaPourtabatabaie: Windows, or rather the MSVCRT, does not natively support this. You could probably work around by either opening a file with "temporary" hint (which, unless you run out of physical memory, is mostly equivalent to an in-memory file) or by creating an anonymous file mapping (which, too, is a kind of "memory buffer"), then call `_open_osfhandle()` on the `HANDLE` followed by calling `_fdopen()`. That gives you a `FILE*`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a comment above, but I'll flesh it out for an answer.

Since your API expects a FILE handle, the easiest way would be to create a file on an in-memory filesystem, such as something mounted with ramfs or tmpfs on Linux.

There's one of these created by default on most Linux systems under /dev/shm, so creating any file under there will still exist as an actual file, but will only exist in memory. Of course, if you reboot, the contents of the file will be lost. I also don't think it can be paged to disk, so try and avoid writing huge files or you'll take up all the space in your memory.

Comment: @Dariusz - I realise this now, hence commenting on Damon's answer above.

Comment: How would this work on Windows? It doesn't support `fmemopen` nor `open_memstream`.